# Перевод из формата XML в CSV

Tags: c#, xml, csv

Написать программу, которая будет читать файлы в xml формате и переводить его в формат csv в таком виде: "|Tag;"пустое место для перевода";". Текст для перевода на английском. Просто дайте направление, код за себя делать я не прошу.

Comment: Нууу и что у Вас получилось? А что именно не получилось?

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации, добавьте описание конкретных проблем, с которыми вы столкнулись.

Comment: С такой постановкой вопроса мы можем только на msdn и nuget отправить. Приведите примеры файла и кода, что ль.

Comment: Направление - System.Xml.Linq.XDocument, System.IO.TextWriter, System.Text.StringBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [пример от microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx) для парсинга XML, берете разбираете на нужные вам составляющие и записываете в csv

```
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

String xmlString =
    @"<bookstore>
        <book genre='autobiography' publicationdate='1981-03-22' ISBN='1-861003-11-0'>
            <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
            <author>
                <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
                <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
            </author>
            <price>8.99</price>
        </book>
    </bookstore>";

// Create an XmlReader
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("book");
    reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
    string genre = reader.Value;
    output.AppendLine("The genre value: " + genre);

    reader.ReadToFollowing("title");
    output.AppendLine("Content of the title element: " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
}

OutputTextBlock.Text = output.ToString();
```

Comment: Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить или изменить, и ответ потеряет ценность).